# Amount of derivatives for a scalar function with $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued argument.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a general smooth $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ with $\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d$,
How many $n$-th order derivatives are there?

Comment: Anything wrong with the post? I don't get the downvote.

Comment: I find it unclear. And I guess the title should read "...valued _argu_ment". To be clear, you mean a function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$? And what kind of derivatives do you mean? In a multi-variate setting the term is not quite clear.

All in all, you could have invested a little more effort into the question. Personally, though, I would (and in fact did) not cast a downvote.

Comment: @m_l Smooth setting is only to simplify the question a little bit. One can replace the statement as assuming all (classical) derivatives up to $n$th order exist (so in PDE standard, $D^\alpha f$ exists in the classical way, where $\alpha$ is a multi-index with $|\alpha| = n$). The core of the question is the amount of derivatives. I couldn't figure out how to deal with the fact $\partial^2 f/\partial x\partial y = \partial^2 f/\partial y\partial x$. So...

Comment: I assumed as much. I also assumed that by "derivatives" you meant "partial derivatives". The term is just a little ambiguous (think directional derivatives, total derivative…).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $n$th order derivative corresponds to $k_i$ derivatives in the $i$th direction, with $k_i\geqslant0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^dk_i=n$. The correspondance with $(k_i)$ is bijective as soon as the derivatives commute, for example if the function is smooth enough.

These $d$-uples are enumerated by the coefficient of $t^n$ in $(1-t)^{-d}$. The expansion of $(1-t)^{-d}$ is 
$$
\sum\limits_{n}{n\choose d-1}t^{n-d+1},
$$ 
hence the desired number of derivatives is 
$$
{n+d-1\choose d-1}={n+d-1\choose n}.
$$